# How to fix Windows 11 not starting?

Tags: boot, windows-11

Summary: Windows 11 computer does not start. It sometimes lets me in randomly (~1 out of 20 times). `chkdsk` and `sfc` did not spot any issues. Neither did [Windows Memory Diagnostics](http://hs.windows.microsoft.com/hhweb/content/m-en-us/p-6.2/id-4edd5f80-def2-4d32-965c-116d49fb9872/). Restored to a previous restore point but problem persists. Did not try invasive measures such as resetting the PC.

I have a Windows 11 computer that stopped working all of a sudden. When I turned on the computer one day it started displaying following screen:

[image]

[image]

followed by a blue screen with some SOS options. I restarted the computer couple of times and also tried automatic repair but each time encountered the error. I then restored the system to a previous restore point and my computer was able to boot up.

[image]

However the problem did not end there. When I restarted the computer, I ran into the same error! I kept trying the restart and automatic repair options with no success. Then I selected option 1 from below and the computer was able to boot.

[image]

I think it was just a fluke because restarting the computer again gave me the error. I am mentioning it to provide as much details as possible. Other things I have noticed when the computer did boot (may or may not be related):

- ethernet does not work. says cable is not plugged in. kept unplugging and plugging it back and then ethernet did work once. but usually it doesn't
- I use WSL2 and VS Code (when opened from WSL2) got into an endless loop opening remote as described [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/4450). this was the reason I restarted my computer the first time after the problem.

Current Status: I am logged in as I am writing this question. After many retries (restarts and letting the computer be without power for sometime), I was able to get in. I have tried running `chkdsk` and `sfc` and did not see any errors:

[image]
[image]

Obviously my end goal is how I can fix this weird issue, but any help that can help me determine *if this is an OS issue or a hardware issue* would also help.

Sorry for lengthy post but I wanted to provide as much details as possible.

Below is the System Information if it helps:

[image]

and result of running Windows Memory Diagnostics:

[image]

Comment: A couple of things:  (a) the post is so long it is not focused.  Create at the bottom 2 or 3 critical lines (one line each) here is what is wrong.  (b) run a complete set of manufacturer's hardware diagnostics to see if there are hardware issues.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I summarized the issue at the very top. Re: (b) I don't have any manufacturer's hardware diagnostics.

Answer (score 2):

> It sometimes lets me in randomly (~1 out of 20 times). chkdsk and sfc
> did not spot any issues. Restored to a previous restore point but
> problem persists.

**First,** see if you can find diagnostics for the major components.  Memtest86.exe for memory.  Get the Disk Manufacturer's drive test app and test these two things.

Also, update BIOS (UEFI).

**Second,** assuming hardware is in decent shape, run a Windows 11 Repair Install.  Keep Everything is NOT invasive - it leaves you where you left off. Do back up important documents first "just in case"

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

Windows 11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Download. When complete, run the downloaded file. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to **Keep Everything** Do this.

Note that a Windows 11 Repair Install will also update drivers from the Microsoft Update Catalog.

See if the basic Repair helps here.

**Third,** if not, then you are looking at more serious OS damage and / or Windows User Profile damage.

Either way at this point, back up completely and reinstall Windows 11.

Comment: I would add update UEFI, if available.

Comment: Nice point. I added that. I also added that a Repair Install will update drivers from the Microsoft Driver Catalog.

Comment: memtest86 gave me a blank screen. others have run into the same issue. is there any difference between Windows 11 Repair Install and reset PC?

Comment: Reset will give you the option to Keep Data.  If Windows is running well enough Repair may also be able to Keep Apps and Data.   You may however have a hardware issue

Comment: I ran [Windows Memory Diagnostics](http://hs.windows.microsoft.com/hhweb/content/m-en-us/p-6.2/id-4edd5f80-def2-4d32-965c-116d49fb9872/) and it did not find any problems with the RAM. I can post screenshot if you like.

Comment: If no hardware errors then try Repair Install and if that does not work, then the last step was to reinstall Windows.